# Properties of Cointegration

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Suppose Xt , Yt and Wt are all I(1) scalar series.  a) If Xt and Yt are cointegrated and Wt and Xt are also cointegrated, then are Yt and Wt necessarily cointegrated? b) Suppose that Xt , Yt and Wt are cointegrated. Are Xt and Yt necessarily cointegrated?